# NTP, Unix and Messaging

Tags: unix-timestamp, ntp, time.h

I have two machines and both of them are set to UTC by the same NTP server. I have them set up so that Machine A sends messages to Machine B at time T and Machine B receives these messages at T + N. The messages seem to be receivable at Machine B for any positive value of N and Im wondering if anyone can tell me of a way to get Machine B to receive these messages at values of N which are less than zero.

The application of this is for frivolous message passing around magnetised water coolers where varying flux densities are related through Brown Capacitors on the fly.

I dont think this problem is one which can be solved in an instant but might merit some responses from those who know what Im talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the type or code that. Say Machine B = 0 and Machine A = 1 or if you have them both in a way that Time is greater than N so the overall outcome is of T + N is a positive outcome. The second code that I added was to unscramble the message but I couldn't mix it with my old code so if you could tweak it to your code it could fix your problem. So I removed all the unscrambling code and put a list code so when it is transmitted it should be fixed

```
Message = input("Please put your message")
Machine_B = 0
Machine_A = 1

while Machine_B <= Machine_A:
    Machine_B -= 1
    if Machine_B = -10
       Machine_B += 1
       print(Message)
    else:
       Machine_B -= 1



  message1 =[Message]
  print(message1)
```

Comment: Ive tried your code and it partially works but the message reads "egassem ruoy tup esaelP" at machine B. It does solve the problem of passing messages of values of N less than zero but the message is too mangled to make much sense of it. Any further help you can offer would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show me your original code for the project so I can see the problem and what is the message supposed to be originally

Comment: Dr Emit Brown wont allow the source code to be released.

Comment: Ok, that's fine give me a little time to work something out but do you know what the message was supposed to be so I can work out the kinks.

Comment: Well according to the code you gave the message is supposed to read "Please put your message" and it works fine for values greater than N when implemented in C, but when the value of N is less than zero, the message arrives at machine B before its sent from machine A and reads "egassem ruoy tup esaelP".

Comment: I wouldnt go to any effort trying to improve your code here. I think your code woks fine right up until the eternal -10 problem which lasts forever. Thankfully this is a problem that can be solved yesterday and so it almost works.